# "characteristic of this ongoing phase"

Tags: adjective-phrases

> *Then, in the West, a noonday crisis occurred as Christianity clashed with modernity, with secularization and a popular belief in “the death of God” **characteristic of this ongoing phase**.*

http://halik.cz/cs/tvorba/clanky-eseje/clanek/220/

Does a native speaker find the above sentence OK? I have the problems with the passage in bold. I would use (a) … *belief in “the death of God”, so characteristic of this ongoing phase*; (b)  … *belief in “the death of God”, which is characteristic of this ongoing phase*. I found the sentence unclear.  Or am I wrong and everything is all right?

Comment: The phrase itself is fine, but it isn't entirely grammatical as written.  It looks like this is a transcription from a lecture by a non-native speaker, though, and so not unusual.

Comment: What do you mean that  "it isn't entirely grammatical as written"?

Comment: It should be "... with secularization and a popular belief in "the death of God" **that are** characteristic of this ongoing phase".  As written it's unclear what the speaker wants to say is *characteristic*.  It's still too wordy, but it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the original sentence sounds fine. Both options (a) and (b) change the meaning a little bit, I think. In particular, I think option (b) says that only  *belief in “the death of God”* is characteristic of the phase, and leaves *secularization* hanging.

I would consider splitting the sentence up to make it easier to digest.

> Then, in the West, a noonday crisis occurred as Christianity clashed
>   with modernity. Secularization and a popular belief in “the death of
>   God” were characteristics of this ongoing phase.